# Copying multiple files from one bucket to another

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

In one request, I would like to be able to copy multiple files that are specific from one bucket to another.  I have the standard code for a single file, which I have to iterate over and cause multiple requests in order to copy multiple files.  Is there a way to give a list of files that I want copied over from one bucket to another, and do it in only one request?  This is what my code looks like now:

```
for(int x=0; x < test.length; x++){
CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest();
                request.SourceBucket = tempBucket;
                request.SourceKey = imagekeys[x];
                request.DestinationBucket = stagingBucket;
                request.DestinationKey = imageUrl_Large_key;
                request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;

                    S3Response response = client.CopyObject(request);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to how the buckets work, I'm pretty sure there is no way to do a mass copy as part of a single request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use S3DirectoryInfo class and CopyTo method to copy the folder key  between buckets.
but it will perform one request for each file to move to target bucket and although it is more elegant way to do it.for example I used AWSSDK 3.1.6 #C .net 3.5 :

```
        public static void MoveFiles()
        {
            BasicAWSCredentials basicCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("your access key", "your secret key");
            AmazonS3Config configurationClient = new AmazonS3Config();
            configurationClient.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1;
            try
            {
                using (AmazonS3Client clientConnection = new AmazonS3Client(basicCredentials, configurationClient))
                {
                    S3DirectoryInfo source = new S3DirectoryInfo(clientConnection, "sourcebucketname", "sourcefolderkey");
                    S3DirectoryInfo target = new S3DirectoryInfo(clientConnection, "targetbucketname", "destinationbucketname");
                    source.CopyTo(target);

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }



        }
```